# Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '23/05/1994' to data type int

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

```
declare @DOB int
declare @age int
select @DOB=coalesce(@DOB+'23/05/1994','')
set @age=DATEDIFF(YEAR,@DOB,GETDATE())

select @age

(or)

select DATEDIFF(MONTH,'23/05/1994','23/06/1995')
```

The conversion failed while converting the varchar value `'23/05/1994'` to data type `int`.

I am getting this response when executing the above queries, help me out please.

Comment: `coalesce(@DOB+'23/05/1994','')` what are you trying to do here?

Comment: Huh?  Why would a date of birth be typed as an integer?

Comment: Use : `MM/DD/YYYY` format

Comment: I am sorry unexpectedly i pasted that line over there.select @DOB=coalesce(@DOB+'23/05/1994','')

Comment: What's the expected result of that conversion?

Comment: Age difference by Year @jarlh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using the `dd/mm/yyyy` format, instead of that use `mm/dd/yyyy` format. For your case you need to covert the date into `mm/dd/yyyy` by the `CONVERT(DATETIME, 'date', 105)`.

```
select @DOB=coalesce(@DOB+'23/05/1994','')
```

the above query is invalid, hope you need to add the day/month to the date value, in this case you can use [`DATEADD`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms186819.aspx)

So the working code:

```
declare @DOB int = 2;
declare @age int;
DECLARE @DateOfBirth DATETIME;
--select @DOB=coalesce(@DOB + '23/05/1994','')
SELECT @DateOfBirth=DATEADD(DAY, @DOB, CONVERT( DATETIME, '23/05/1994', 105));
set @age=DATEDIFF(YEAR,@DateOfBirth,GETDATE())
select @age;

--(or)

select DATEDIFF(MONTH, CONVERT(DATETIME,'23/05/1994', 105), CONVERT(DATETIME,'23/06/1995', 105));
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try setting DOB as date to make the routine easier. It would end up like this:

```
declare @DOB date
declare @age int
select @DOB='05/23/1994'
set @age=DATEDIFF(YEAR,@DOB,GETDATE())
select @age
```